# Page text: disable conversion of HTML links to HTML entities

Tags: mediawiki

I have an old Mediawiki site (1.6.x) and I need to upgrade it to 1.31. This site has many pages and many of them have text with html links in the HTML format such as:

```
<a href="/index.php?title=My_PAGE">Text</a>
```

I am able to upgrade its database to 1.31. However, in display, the above html links are converted to

```
&lt;a href="/index.php?title=My_PAGE"&gt;TEXT&lt;/a&gt;
```

How can I prevent Mediawiki (1.31.x) from performing the above conversion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unable to find a method, I simply added the following two lines in `public function execute()` of ExampleTemplate.php

```
    $html = str_replace('&lt;', '<', $html);
    $html = str_replace('&gt;', '>', $html);
```

Please let me know if you know a better way.

Comment: This is dangerous as this enables full html capabilities for everyone who can edit the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

I am uncertain presently how to prevent MediaWiki from changing your code, but a possible solution would be to use this

https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Replace_Text

after the upgrade to replace **`&lt;`** with **`<`** and **`&gt;`** with **`>`**

Comment: Thanks for chiming in! Do you mean replace '&lt;' or '&gt;' in database?  '<a href="/index.php?title=My_PAGE">Text</a>' is stored in the MySQL database. No '&lt;' or '&gt;' is stored.